# C# to C++ Conversion: Searching Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, list, vector, lambda

I have a working (well, buildable, but WIP nonetheless) game that I coded in C# using XNA a while back, and I'm now converting the game to C++. In converting some of my methods, I'm encountering the error that I cannot really find anything equivalent to some of the Array methods, such as FindAll, Find, and Exists. I'm using vectors and any help on an equivalent method and how to implement it would be very helpful.

For example, in C# I had:

```
if (Array.Exists(tileList, tile => tile.Position.X == e.Position.X))
```

Where e was some entity, tileList was an array of all the tiles in the game, and tile was obviously the tile in the array.

How could I create something with a near-identical function in C++?

Comment: There are corresponding algorithms in the [`<algorithm>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Whether you can use a lambda expression (as you did in C#) depends on whether you can use C++11 (the syntax would be slightly different then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you probably want something like:

```
if (std::any_of(tileList.begin(), tileList.end(), 
                [](tile e) { return tile.position.X == e.Position.X; }))
    // whatever
```

If you have an older compiler (`std::any_of` was added in C++11, so older compilers don't have it) you could use `std::find` or `std::find_if` instead. As you'd probably guess, these try to find the location of the matching element, not just tell you if one exists, so it'll be a little clumsier to use, but not drastically so (basically, you have to compare the returned position against `tileList.end()` to see whether you got a match or not).

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. However, since tile is a custom class, it is now giving the error that there is no == operator found which takes the left hand type of tile, even though I don't at any point try to use the == operator on a tiles. What might be a solution to this?

Comment: One ways is to define `operator==` for your `Tile` class, something like: `bool operator==(Tile const &other) { return position.X == other.position.X; }`.

Comment: I've just now tried this. I'm getting this error still, and as I was before (although I didn't mention them), am getting "no conversion from const my_func::<lambda_somehexstuff> to Tile" as well as '==' : illegal for class. The errors are all showing in some "xutility" file which I've never dealt with before.

Comment: Oops -- the signature should be `bool operator==(Tile const &other) const ...`. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: On a somewhat related note (only related by the fact that it is in the same project, and also giving the same errors, as well as also using the std::find function...this function is giving me the same three errors:

`Tile Level::GetTileAtPosition(bool screenOrGame, Vector2 position)
 {

  if (screenOrGame)
  {

   return *find(tileList.begin(), tileList.end(), [position](Tile t) { return t.GetPosition() == position / 24; });

  }

  else
  {

   return *find(tileList.begin(), tileList.end(), [position](Tile t) { return t.GetPosition() == position; });

  }

 }`

Comment: @user1340086: Not sure if it'll cure the whole problem, but it looks like that should be `const` as well.

Comment: Sadly, that did nothing for me. I've pastebinned the error and the related function. http://pastebin.com/RuRidr41